# installing fo-Dicom package in vb.net 20014

Tags: fo-dicom

by installing fo-dicom v. 5.0.3 package from "Manage NuGet Packages" in vb.net 2014 from  i encounter following error:

Could not install package 'fo-dicom 5.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

.net version of my project is 4.5.

i have tried to change the version of the .net framework of the project to 4.6.1. but the problem persists.
has anybody any idea to solve the problem?
thanks.